# how to get a basic conversation with socialize:messaging?

Tags: javascript, meteor

i'm trying to get a basic conversation with this code:

JS:

```
var conversation;

Template.messagestpl.onCreated(function(){
    this.subscribe('getUserDataByUsername', 'google', function(){
        Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
            conversation = new Conversation().save();
            var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: 'google'});
            conversation.addParticipant(user);
            conversation.sendMessage("Hello World!1");
            conversation.sendMessage("Hello World!2");
            conversation.sendMessage("Hello World!3");

            conversation.participants().forEach(function(participant){
                console.log(participant.user().username);
            });

        });
    });
});

Template.messagestpl.helpers({
    messagesList: function(){
            return conversation.messages();
    }
});
```

Blaze:

```
<template name="messagestpl">
    messages
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{#each messagesList}}
            {{message}}: {{message.body}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

I'm getting an error message:

**Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined**

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are using the name 'messages' for several different variables. You use it as the template name and then again for the name of the helper function, and it's used again in conversation.messages() for another function. I would first of all rename these so that you know which 'messages' the error is refering to, though I suspect it's the conversation.messages

Comment: iv changed the names and still i am facing same problem.

Comment: I can't see the changes

Comment: and now my friend?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not enough for the subscription to be ready in your case, you also have to wait for the conversation stuff to return, I think. I had to face this just the other day, so I'll look up the code and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this in an answer, for reasons of space, even though it may not be complete.

I would have thought that the problem is that the `conversation` variable is not reactive.

You could either make `conversation` a ReactiveVar, or put `conversation` into a Session variable.

After:

```
           conversation.participants().forEach(function(participant){
            console.log(participant.user().username);
        });
```

put this:

```
Session.set('conversation', conversation);
```

then change the helper function:

```
Template.messagestpl.helpers({
messagesList: function(){
        var conversation = Session.get('conversation');
        return conversation.messages();
}
```

});

I would then think that the Template.afterFlush() would not be needed.

Comment: thats not help :(

btw:
Session.set('conversation', conversation);

thanks you for trying to help!

Comment: Do you need the Tracker.afterFlush()? Did you try removing it?

Comment: yea, and after removing it all get messed up

Comment: hi, unfortunately no i'm building messages (exactly) like facebook by myself, its not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use Sessions. So, hope this short example will help you:

```
Template.convers.events({
'click #addConvers': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: 'google'});

    var conversation = new Conversation().save();
    conversation.addParticipant(user);
    Session.set('converID', conversation._id);
}
});
```

And you need to return from messages collection by conversation id:

```
Template.messagestpl.helpers({
messagesList: function(){
        var sGet = Session.get('converID');
        return Meteor.messages.find({
            conversationId:sGet});
}
});
```